# No longer able to access Wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am no longer able to access the admin panel of a Wordpress site. 2 days ago I added a plugin, loaded some new content, and things were working fine. The client loaded some regular blog posts, and today, it no longer works.

First of all, **the error itself**:

I go to URL: `mydomain.com/wp-admin`, the browser redirects to: `mydomain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

The error message says:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /mother/18/readf.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**What I know so far:**

- Nothing in .htaccess redirects to mother/18/readf.php
- A search of similar errors gives a lot of results where urls within normal sites seem hijacked to sell antidepressants, viagra, etc. When I say normal sites I mean that there are sites that do logistics, 
  https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mother/*/readf.php&safe=off&nfpr=1&start=10
  https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mother/*/readf.php&safe=off&nfpr=1&start=10
- Disabling all plugins doesn't help (I renamed the plugins folder and then tried to log into the admin).
- Searching the database for `readf.php` or `mother` doesn't show anything obvious.
- The client claims to only have made changes to content since yesterday, when the site admin was still working. (Yes, claims... they have superadmin access, so this might not be true).

Has anyone come across this issue? Any ideas on what I can look for next?

Comment: There was a vulnerability in wordpress i made a post on how to mitigate if your site has been comprised. But its hard if have no access to admin, have you tried migrating the site locally to check for these issues? My post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830829/how-do-i-to-figure-out-where-inserted-possibly-malicious-javascript-code-is-co/29832896#29832896

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will first test it locally and see where this takes me.

Comment: i suggest you follow the steps given by the Answerer first since he's more qualify but yeah glade i could give some light unto this issue.

Comment: Advice from @songdogtech below is very good, and also consider site checking services. There are vulnerability scanning services such as sitelock, a fairly new automatic patching one in the netherlands that I forget the name of right now, and very new services to block execution in real-time if unexpected code is discovered such as ionCube24. Combining real-time code execution protection with a vulnerability scanner to possibly find out how a site was infected in the first place could easily prevent disaster and allow you to act calmly without panic.  Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube24

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you got hacked. Time to fix it right the first time, or you will get hacked again. You need to replace all core WP files/folders (except wp-config.php and wp-content), but scan the uploads folder and theme for exploit code and modified files or added files, like `readf.php`. Replace all plugins, too.

Also scan the database for `eval` code and added administrators. (See "My Site was Hacked" below).

Change all host, FTP and WordPress passwords in the process. Scan your own PC for malware that might have grabbed logins and passwords.

Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host.

Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) at WordPress.org.

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks) at WordPress.org.

Comment: Its been a crazy week you too i assume? :D